# move operation with pimpl idiom

Tags: c++, unique-ptr, move-semantics, pimpl-idiom

In the following code I am attempting to use a move assignment within the PIMPL idiom, but the code does not compile.

struct.hpp:

```
#pragma once

#include <memory>

struct A {
  std::unique_ptr<struct B> m_x;
  A(int x);
  ~A();
};
```

struct.cpp:

```
#include "struct.hpp"

struct B {
  int x;
};

A::A(int x) : m_x{new B} { m_x->x = x; }
A::~A() = default;
```

main.cpp:

```
#include <utility>
#include "struct.hpp"

int main()
{
  A a(2);
  A b(3);
  a = std::move(b);
  return 0;
}
```

While `struct.cpp` compiles with no warning, ```main.cpp`` does not, giving the error:

```
$ g++ -c -std=c++17 -o main.o main.cpp
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:8:18: error: use of deleted function ‘A& A::operator=(const A&)’
    8 |   a = std::move(b);
... (etc) ...
```

It is clear that the copy assignment `A::operator=(const A&)` is deleted because it is deleted for a `std::unique_ptr`.
But why does the compiler attempt to use it in first place? Shouldn't `std::move` enforce the use of the move assignment, which is valid and defined for a `std::unique_ptr`?

Comment: With a user-declared destructor, the compiler no longer automatically generates a [move constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_constructor). The same applies for the [move assignment operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_assignment).

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux It's serving as a forward declaration of `B` in this context.

Comment: @NathanPierson uhm, you are right. Actually I am forced to declare a default destructor, otherwise the code does not compile. I suppose I would need to define a default move assignment?

Comment: You should prefer `std::make_unique<B>` to `new B` in modern C++ code. In this case, I don't think it technically makes any difference but as a general rule it helps avoid an edge case memory leak, and it reduces the use of `new` which is usually code smell and can indicate possible bugs.

Comment: @francesco Yes, see for instance [this](https://godbolt.org/z/o93EE85fa) which compiles.

Comment: Compiles if I completely remove `A::~A();` - live - https://godbolt.org/z/95TvW8nqq  What error were you getting before you declared the default destructor ?

Comment: @RichardCritten It does not compile if the code is split into the sources as in the question. That is the purpose of the PIMPL idiom: the struct B is forward declared and main.cpp does not know anything about it.

Comment: @francesco have move `main` up the file (hard to simulate multiple files) - https://godbolt.org/z/sTaro3xdK

Comment: @RichardCritten I created a MCVE for you: https://wandbox.org/permlink/7mKHWkKtqXZK56ef User declared special member functions are necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While `std::unique_ptr` does have a move assignment operator and it certainly seems natural to want to make use of that fact to make `A` move-assignable, the user-declared constructor runs into problems.

cppreference on the [move assignment operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_assignment):

> **Implicitly-declared move assignment operator**
>
> If no user-defined move assignment operators are provided for a class type (`struct`, `class`, or `union`), and all of the following is true:
>
> - there are no user-declared copy constructors;
> - there are no user-declared move constructors;
> - there are no user-declared copy assignment operators;
> - there are no user-declared destructors,
>
> then the compiler will declare a move assignment operator as an `inline` public member of its class with the signature `T& T::operator=(T&&)`.

Note the last bullet point: `A` has a user-declared destructor, so you don't get the implicitly-declared move assignment operator.

If we want to make `A` move-assignable with a minimum of effort, we can explicitly declare the move assignment operator and request the default implementation as follows:

struct.hpp:

```
#include <memory>

struct A {
  std::unique_ptr<struct B> m_x;
  A(int x);
  A& operator=(A&&) noexcept;
  ~A();
};
```

struct.cpp:

```
#include "struct.hpp"

struct B {
    int x;
};

A::A(int x) : m_x{ new B } { m_x->x = x; }
A::~A() = default;
A& A::operator=(A&&) noexcept = default;
```

We need to declare the destructor and move assignment operator in our header file but defer definition until the source file that's aware of the fully-defined `B`. Note that I manually specify that the assignment operator is `noexcept`, because if I don't make it `default` at point of declaration it won't be `noexcept`, which the implicitly-declared move assignment operator would be.

Comment: @francesco You omitted the `struct.cpp` portion that defines `B` and `A::A(int)`.

Comment: I omitted on purpose. In the PIMPL idiom I hide the actual implementation of B in a separate source file. The main.cpp source only includes the header of the wrapping struct A, and B is forward declared.

Comment: I see. If I were right that would be a linker error error not a compilation error. Editing my answer.

Comment: @francesco Note that you'll also want to also do the same for the move constructor.